# Fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value on sendSynchronousRequest

Tags: ios, swift

While sending a NSURLRequest:

```
var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
var err: AutoreleasingUnsafePointer<NSError?> = nil
var response: AutoreleasingUnsafePointer<NSURLResponse?> = nil    
var data = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: response, error: err) as NSData
```

On the last string I've got the error:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

This error appears only on IOS 8 simulators. With IOS 7.1 simulators the app works fine without any errors. 
Before sending a request, I tried to log out requests with `println(request)` and with IOS 7.1 I've got:

```
<NSMutableURLRequest: 0x7b787130> { URL: http://www.example.com/api/search?name=test&page=1 }
```

with IOS 8:

```
<NSMutableURLRequest: 0x7b6246d0> { URL: http://www.example.com/api/search?name=test&page=1, headers: (null) }
```

Then I assumed that the problem was in request headers, so I set one:

```
request.setValue("application/json; charset=UTF-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
```

But unfortunately it didn't help, the app still works only on IOS 7.1 simulators, but not on IOS 8. Please tell me what am I doing wrong?

By the way, I'm using Xcode 6 beta 3, if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error with my App, this is what I changed my code to, after which everything is working fine.  Please notice that towards the end of sendSynchronousRequest 'as NSData' is removed.

```
var dataVal =  NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: response, error:nil)

if ( dataVal == nil ) {
  // Handle error here
}

// Everything is fine! Rest of the code
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Harish, your answer makes sense but all it does is mask the fact that the data coming back is nil. The real issue is that the server is NOT being pinged. I tested this out by using postman to send my server post requests which was fine but the server showed no activity for when i run a request from my app. Any ideas?